# Vertx/RxJava/Retrofit blocking

Tags: kotlin, server, retrofit, vert.x

I'm working on a Kotlin/Vertx/RxJava/Retrofit server, but some calls are blocking Vertx when calling an external API that takes too long.

The original handler makes the call:

```
val response = weatherService.getWeatherSummaryByCity(countryCode = queryParams[0], adminCode = queryParams[1], cityName = queryParams[2])
```

This in turn executes the external call:

```
fun getWeatherSummaryByCity(countryCode: String, adminCode: String, cityName: String): WeatherSummary? {
    val citiesList = externalAPI.getLocationByCityName(countryCode = countryCode, adminCode = adminCode, cityName = cityName)
    var weatherSummary : WeatherSummary? = null

    citiesList
        .doOnError { error -> print(error) }
        .filter { cityList -> !cityList.isEmpty() }
        .map { cityList -> cityList[0] }
        .filter { city -> city.Key != null && !city.Key.isEmpty() }
        .subscribe( { city: City -> weatherSummary = createWeatherSummary(city) } )

    return weatherSummary
}
```

And here's the interface used by Retrofit

```
interface ExternalAPI {

@GET("/locations/{version}/cities/{countryCode}/{adminCode}/search.json")
fun getLocationByCityName(
        @Path("version") version: String = "v1",
        @Path("countryCode") countryCode: String,
        @Path("adminCode") adminCode: String,
        @Query("q") cityName: String,
        @Query("apikey") apiKey: String = key, 
        @Query("details") details: String = "true",
        @Query("language") language: String = "en-US"): Observable<List<City>>
}
```

The code as is works, but if the externalAPI takes too long it blocks Vertx. Same happens when I try this:

```
Json.encodePrettily(response)
```

and the response is too big. Any ideas to avoid the blocking?

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to handle your problem:

1. use an async http client to fetch the *getLocationByCityName*. I am not using retrofit, but looking at this: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests it has out of the box support for it.
2. Blocking code can always be executed on a dedicated worker thread by calling *vertx.executeblocking*. This can be read up here: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code

I would suggest option 1 as it is more clean.